# Problems with Cypress in a Windows PC

Tags: cypress

I have installed Cypress in two PCs with similar features. On the first one Cypress works, it's fast and doesn't give me any problems. On the second one I'm having difficulties:

- The cy.visit command takes a very long time to reach my site, even 60 seconds. Actually the site has no problem of reachability
- if I close the test execution and relaunch it, the test runner opens in an "about.blank" page

I've tried everything, uninstalled Cypress, cleared cypress cache. I have uninstalled node.js and npm. I then reinstalled the whole thing. But the problems remain. If you need more information I remain available. Below what is printed in powershell during the first test that contains a "cy.visit" (it took more than 80 seconds in all)

```
GET /__/ 200 45.608 ms - -
GET /__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.css 200 68.125 ms - -
GET /chrome-variations/seed?osname=win&channel=stable&milestone=89 304 652.798 ms - -
POST /ListAccounts?gpsia=1&source=ChromiumBrowser&json=standard 200 604.179 ms - -
GET /__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js 200 71.181 ms - -
GET /__cypress/static/favicon.ico 200 4.437 ms - -
GET /__cypress/iframes/integration/pr/te.js 200 7.769 ms - 843
GET /__cypress/runner/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 200 3.737 ms - 76120
GET /v1/pages/ChRDaHJvbWUvODkuMC40Mzg5LjExNBIQCcmLdcaTM2VsEgUNkWGVThIXCQPNs0E5ZBKtEgUNL4g-ghIFDZFhlU4=?alt=proto 200 385.975 ms - -
GET /__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Cintegration%5Cpr%5Cte.js 200 8102.285 ms - -
GET /__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Csupport%5Cindex.js 200 8122.208 ms - -
GET /__/ 200 1.715 ms - -
GET /__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.css 200 1.567 ms - -
GET /__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js 200 4.923 ms - -
GET /__cypress/iframes/integration/pr/te.js 200 2.085 ms - 849
GET /__cypress/runner/fonts/fa-solid-900.woff2 200 2.107 ms - 76120
GET /__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Csupport%5Cindex.js 200 9.996 ms - -
GET /__cypress/tests?p=cypress%5Cintegration%5Cpr%5Cte.js 200 5.663 ms - -
GET /v1/pages/ChRDaHJvbWUvODkuMC40Mzg5LjExNBIQCXTM6vS20UQ9EgUNkWGVThIXCRevpbqZx6oNEgUNL4g-ghIFDZFhlU4=?alt=proto 200 87.250 ms - -
GET /men/1-1-hummingbird-printed-t-shirt.html 200 201.834 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/theme.css 200 358.023 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css 200 221.726 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_imageslider/css/homeslider.css 200 299.205 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/custom.css 200 294.395 ms - -
GET /themes/core.js 200 177.118 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/js/theme.js 200 537.278 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_emailsubscription/views/js/ps_emailsubscription.js 200 148.071 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js 200 281.471 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_imageslider/js/responsiveslides.min.js 200 237.210 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_imageslider/js/homeslider.js 200 388.981 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_searchbar/ps_searchbar.js 200 186.480 ms - -
GET /modules/ps_shoppingcart/ps_shoppingcart.js 200 272.364 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/js/custom.js 200 235.551 ms - -
GET /img/logo.png 200 219.762 ms - -
GET /2-large_default/hummingbird-printed-t-shirt.jpg 200 1297.510 ms - -
GET /2-home_default/hummingbird-printed-t-shirt.jpg 200 164.662 ms - -
GET /modules/blockreassurance/img/ic_verified_user_black_36dp_1x.png 200 217.993 ms - -
GET /modules/blockreassurance/img/ic_local_shipping_black_36dp_1x.png 200 160.820 ms - -
GET /modules/blockreassurance/img/ic_swap_horiz_black_36dp_1x.png 200 147.800 ms - -
GET /img/m/1.jpg 200 115.767 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css 200 12482.121 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/082a71677e756fb75817e8f262a07cb4.svg 200 133.134 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/8b05d51ede908907d65695558974d86f.svg 200 135.111 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/themes/base/minified/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png 200 193.227 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/b1db819132e64a3e01911a1413c33acf.svg 200 499.059 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/570eb83859dc23dd0eec423a49e147fe.woff2 200 228.871 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/19c1b868764c0e4d15a45d3f61250488.woff2 200 268.473 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/199038f07312bfc6f0aabd3ed6a2b64d.woff2 200 230.125 ms - -
GET /v1/pages/ChRDaHJvbWUvODkuMC40Mzg5LjExNBIQCSH1MkjtAoVnEgUNu1dWahIXCbpTXag6Wh1tEgUNjsJ8QRIFDctunW4SEAl5ngwDYftELxIFDYOoWz0=?alt=proto 200 101.980 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/ffddcb3736980b23405b31142a324b62.svg 200 13351.874 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/99db8adec61e4fcf5586e1afa549b432.svg 200 13350.633 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/e049aeb07a2ae1627933e8e58d3886d2.svg 200 13445.685 ms - -
POST /carrello 200 389.199 ms - -
POST /module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax 200 388.407 ms - -
GET /__cypress/runner/fonts/fa-regular-400.woff2 200 6.671 ms - 13600
GET /carrello?action=show 200 443.053 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery.ui.theme.min.css 200 133.347 ms - -
GET /js/jquery/ui/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css 200 149.125 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/custom.css 200 145.832 ms - -
GET /themes/classic/assets/css/theme.css 200 165.264 ms - -
```

EDIT: thanks to the advice received from the chat https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress I concluded that the problem was related to Chrome. I uninstalled and reinstalled the browser and the problem was resolved.